# What am I loading from agaricus.txt.train?

Tags: python, machine-learning, matrix, xgboost, libsvm

In the [basic walkthrough example](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/demo/guide-python/basic_walkthrough.py) by XGBoost, we load the dataset first.

```
>>> dtrain = xgb.DMatrix('../data/agaricus.txt.train')
[20:37:22] 6513x127 matrix with 143286 entries loaded from ../data/agaricus.txt.train
>>> dtest = xgb.DMatrix('../data/agaricus.txt.test')
[20:37:23] 1611x127 matrix with 35442 entries loaded from ../data/agaricus.txt.test
```

However, the data sets seem to contain 127 features, as opposed to 126 as documented by XGBoost's [R package](https://rdrr.io/cran/xgboost/man/agaricus.test.html).

```
>>> dtrain.num_col()
127
```

In addition, [`xgboost.Booster.predict`](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.Booster.predict) will return a matrix of size (nsample, nfeats + 1) when `pred_contribs` is set to `True`. Since `preds` has 128 columns, we can concluded that `dtrain` contains 127 features.

```
>>> param = {'max_depth':2, 'eta':1, 'silent':1, 'objective':'binary:logistic'}
>>> watchlist = [(dtest, 'eval'), (dtrain, 'train')]
>>> num_round = 2
>>> bst = xgb.train(param, dtrain, num_round, watchlist)
[0] eval-error:0.042831 train-error:0.046522
[1] eval-error:0.021726 train-error:0.022263
>>> preds = bst.predict(dtest, output_margin=True, pred_contribs=True, approx_contribs=True)
>>> preds.shape
(1611, 128)
```

What's going on here? Did [`xgboost.DMatrix`](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.DMatrix) mistakenly consider the label as the 127th feature? If the [libsvm format txt file](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/demo/data/agaricus.txt.train) is parsed correctly, then why does `preds` have 128 columns?